# WPF Change Grid.ColumnSpan on trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**tl;dr:**  I want detail views to appear in 2 columns if 2 items are selected, and to span 2 columns if only 1 item is selected.

I have a DockPanel with 2 ListBoxes docked on the left and a 2-column Grid on the right.

When an item is selected in listBox1, I display a details view in Column 0 of the Grid.

When an item is selected in listBox2, I display a details view in Column 1 of the Grid.

```
    <DockPanel>

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem1}"/>                    
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem2}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding SelectedItem1}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplateSelector}"/>
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedItem2}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplateSelector}"/>
        </Grid>

    </DockPanel>
```

This works fine.  However, I'd like to modify it so that the details view will span **both grid columns** when there is an item selected in one of the ListBoxes but not in the other.

My first thought was to create a couple of DataTriggers that modify the ColumnSpan of the ContentControls based on the SelectedIndex of the ListBoxes.

This works fine for the details view that normally lives in Grid.Column="0".  However, it doesn't work for the details view that normally lives in Grid.Column="1" since the original column number is hard-coded:

```
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding SelectedItem1}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplateSelector}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listBox2, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                                <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>

            <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedItem2}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SelectedItemTemplateSelector}">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
                                <!--Can't modify Grid.Column since it's hardcoded above!-->
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
```

If I could create a DataTrigger that could do a value comparison against ListBox.SelectedIndex (ie. >=0), then I could avoid hard-coding the column numbers in the first place.

Is there any way to do something like this in XAML?

Answer (score 1):

You can always do the hidden element binding trick. the example below, you just change bindme to 2, and the Grids span will change. I do this on all types of stuff you can't animate with a storyboard.

<Rectangle x:Name="bindme" Width="0" Height="0" Tag="1" />

<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding Tag, ElementName=bindme}">